Constructing a Curve from a Differentiable Function's Normal Lines at a Fixed Distance.
I've been experimenting with a graphing calculator and stumbled upon an interesting geometric construction involving functions and their normal lines. Here's the problem I'm trying to solve:
Let's consider a differentiable function $ f$ defined on a closed interval. For a given positive real number $ r > 0 $, we perform the following construction for every point $ (x, f(x)) $ on the graph of $ f $:
List item

Draw the normal line to the graph of $ f $ at the point $ (x, f(x)) $.
From the points on this normal line, select the one that is a distance $ r $ away from $ (x, f(x)) $ and has a $ y $-coordinate greater than $ f(x) $. If there are two such points with equal $ y $-coordinates, choose the one with the smaller $ x $-coordinate.

The result of this process is a new curve, which I'll denote as $ F $. This curve is not necessarily a function.
For instance, consider the function $ f(x) = (x-1)(x+2)(2x-1) $ with $ r = 0.1 $. The resulting curve from the above mapping is shown below:

Additionally, here's an animation showing the function $ f(x) = (x-1)(x+2)(2x-1) $ with $ r $ varying between $ 0 $ and $ 2 $, and the corresponding curve $ F $:

My question is: How can we mathematically determine the curve $ F $ given the function $ f $ and the distance $ r $?
This problem appears to be quite challenging, especially for ugly functions like the  antiderivative of the Weierstrass function. Any insights or methods to approach this would be greatly appreciated.

Your question appears to be the "constant imposer function"/parallel curve special case here: Is "imposing" one function onto another ever used in mathematics? <> As for graphs of Weierstrass functions, they don't have normal lines (because they don't have tangent lines).

Yes, you presumably want to assume that $f$ is continuously differentiable, not just continuous.

@AndrewD.Hwang I would never expect that this question is dup.
